# Xtext - Couldn't resolve reference to Object

Tags: eclipse, xtext, resolve

I'm new to Xtext and having a problem with a simple Xtext program:

my grammar looks like this:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate domainmodel "http://www.xtext.org/example/domainmodel/Domainmodel"

Library:
    (books+=Book)*;

Book:
    'Book' 
    isbn=ID 
    title=STRING 
    (subtitle=STRING)? 
    pages=INT 
    ('sequelof' sequelof=[Book])? 
    ('hardcover'|'softcover');
```

and my script looks like this

```
Book J123 "LotR1" "The Fellowship" 608 hardcover
Book J124 "LotR2" "Two Towers" 510 sequelof J123 hardcover
```

but the "J123" in the second line is red underlined and it says "Couldn't resolve reference to Book 'J123'"

Everthing else works fine, like Content Assist (Strg+Space)

Maybe you can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, references work on `name` properties. I.e. you need to change your grammar to the following:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel with 
org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate domainmodel "http://www.xtext.org/example/domainmodel/Domainmodel"

Library:
  (books+=Book)*;

Book:
  'Book' 
  name=ID 
  title=STRING 
  (subtitle=STRING)? 
  pages=INT 
  ('sequelof' sequelof=[Book])? 
  ('hardcover'|'softcover');
```

If you don't want to do that, you can implement the `IQualifiedName` provider so that it computes the name using the `isbn` property.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response :-)